# How to covert jQuery DataTables to CSV format

Tags: json, csv, datatables, export-to-csv

I am using jquery datatables.
Can you please tell me a way so that i can convert those dat tables to CSV format.
I am getting data as JSON objects.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use tabletools as in [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/index.html) example: it does exactly what you need (and even some more)

Comment: thanks dude for the answer...
I already stumbled on that page. There the person is taking data from the table when it is formed. What if I wanted to take data from JSON object??